# maven-assembly-plugin MojoExecutionException with dependencySet as outputDirectory

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

In my [Khatami](https://github.com/CarePilot/khatami) project I'm using maven to both manage compilation and package up the result into a runnable artifact: executable shell-script at the top-level, `bin/` containing the executable jar and its dependent jars. Please see what I mean [here](https://github.com/CarePilot/khatami/blob/aeeabaffca8b2780590adb954110b1083ae28147/src/main/assembly/khatami).

For reference, here's the salient part of Khatami's [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/CarePilot/khatami/blob/aeeabaffca8b2780590adb954110b1083ae28147/pom.xml):

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>${project.groupId}.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

and the full [`src/main/assembly/src.xml`](https://github.com/CarePilot/khatami/blob/aeeabaffca8b2780590adb954110b1083ae28147/src/main/assembly/src.xml):

```
<assembly>
  <id>dist</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/assembly</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>khatami</include>
      </includes>
      <fileMode>744</fileMode>
      <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

and compilation attempt:

```
$ mvn clean compile assembly:single
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building khatami 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ khatami ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/blt/projects/com/carepilot/repos/khatami/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ khatami ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/blt/projects/com/carepilot/repos/khatami/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ khatami ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/blt/projects/com/carepilot/repos/khatami/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) @ khatami ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/src.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.721s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 18 13:58:30 EDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project khatami: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file 'com.carepilot.khatami:khatami:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT' to archive: /home/blt/projects/com/carepilot/repos/khatami/target/classes isn't a file. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Where am I at fault?

Comment: How are you running your maven build? From command line or from inside an IDE>

Comment: Command line. The last code listing contains the relevant line, beginning with ``$``.

Comment: Have you ever used this project with in eclipse and used some plug-in to import it in to eclipse environment. This looks like some maven configuration problem. I have had this kind of issue and I tracked it to my m2eclipse plugin. (which s**ks .. by the way)

Comment: No, afraid not. I don't make use of any IDE.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The relevant part of the error information is

```
Error adding file 'com.carepilot.khatami:khatami:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT' to archive:
/home/blt/projects/com/carepilot/repos/khatami/target/classes isn't a file.
```

it is expecting a file and it can't find it because the `package` goal isn't running after the `clean` .

if you do `mvn clean compile package assembly:single` it will build successfully.

I would add the `assembly:single` goal to the `package` phase, that way it will build automatically.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>${project.groupId}.Main</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

with the above changes to the configuration you can just issue.

```
mvn clean package
```

and the `assembly:single` goal will be executed automatically.

A better way to do this might be to use the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) instead of doing this manually.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem:

```
Error adding file 'com.carepilot.khatami:khatami:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT' to archive:
/home/blt/projects/com/carepilot/repos/khatami/target/classes isn't a file.
```

Is caused because the project artifact (com.carepilot.khatami:khatami:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT) has not been packaged yet, but is part of the assembly's `<dependencySet>`. You can add `<useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>` to your `<dependencySet>` to resolve the problem.

If you need the project's class file included in the assembly, you can use a `<fileSet>` to include directory `target/classes`.

For example:

```
<assembly>
  <id>dist</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/assembly</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>khatami</include>
      </includes>
      <fileMode>744</fileMode>
      <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Another option would be to attach the assembly to a phase after `packaging`.

**Edit:**
I've also seen this problem in Eclipse when `Resolve Workspace artifacts` is enabled in the Maven build settings.